# How do you search a nested list with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, list, search

I've put a simple search field together to look through a list, but I have nested lists and it is limited to a single level list - how do you modify

I've put it in a fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/marksweb/4CJMe/

What do I need to do to my `if(filter)` in order to also check nested items and not hide the child of a nested list if the result is there?

Demo site; http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3755926/cssTricks/main.html

```
(function ($) {
  // custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
  jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
      return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
  };

  function searchList(header, list) { // header is any element, list is an unordered list
    // create and add the filter form to the header
    var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterform","action":"#"}),
        input = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterinput","type":"text"});
    $(form).append(input).prependTo(header);

    $(input)
      .change( function () {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if(filter) {
            // this finds all links in a list that contain the input,
            // and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
            $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
            $(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
        } else {
            // return to default
            $(list).find("li").slideDown();
        }
        return false;
      })
    .keyup( function () {
        // fire the above change event after every letter
        $(this).change();
    });
  }

  //ondomready
  $(function () {
    searchList($("#main"), $("#contents-list"));
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I've eventually fixed it (but I'm not allowed to answer my own question). Taking things up a level to find li and then return to find ul has fixed things it would seem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix my problems with this now.

My initial problem with trying to access my list was that I couldn't use class selectors for existing content within my exported HTML so I had to add custom IDs and use those with `searchList($("#main"), $("#contents-list"));` which worked successfully.

Then to access nested list items I had to take the filter level up from `<a>` and `<li>` as seen in my question here to access the `<li>` and default to the `<ul>` so the final filter looks like this;

```
        if(filter) {
            // this finds all links in a list that contain the input,
            // and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
            $(list).find("li:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
            $(list).find("li:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
        } else {
            // return to default
            $(list).find("ul").slideDown();
        }
        return false;
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

The search works, but only when the textbox loses focus or enter is pressed.

Change the following line from:

```
$(input).change(function(){
```

to:

```
$(input).keyup(function(){
```

and the functionality seems to start working fine.

I also noticed that the `contains` modification wasn't performing a case-insensitive search, so modifying the following line as so should also fix that:

```
var hasMatch = searchTerms.length == 0 || $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.toLowerCase()) > 0;
```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/4CJMe/4/).

Comment: Thanks. That change/keyup was a fallout from a change to a new method. I must be missing something though because although it works in jsFiddle its not working when I run the local file or the public dropbox url. Could that relate to browser security & running JS?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. I've just copied the jsFiddle to a local file and all seemed to run fine for me. Is there perhaps other things on the page that could conflict with any of the above?

Comment: Perhaps. This is where my limited knowledge doesn't help. The page uses HTML frames (unfortunately) and this sits in a sidebar but I can't see anything that would cause a problem unless frames themselves do. Heres a demo of the site - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3755926/cssTricks/main.html

Comment: My knowledge with frames is also a little shady to be honest, but I knocked up a quick frames test and it also worked fine. Are the JS files being accessed correctly to work on local files?

Comment: Really not sure, I can see on the demo how the keyup event isn't firing, yet when you put the Countries example in, that works fine. I'm a bit stomped, tbh. Perhaps try mimicking the way they've defined the `change()` and `keyup()` events?

Comment: Yeah I had that in there earlier so that exactly what I've just done. I put that original example in which works fine so now I'm just going to have to go through & try to debug it. First problem being the console.log doesn't log at the point the form creates. Oh well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

the example in the tutorial is very good, but it didn't work for my nested lists. I created a different code based on the example and it works very well.

eg. of list (html code):

```
  <h3 id="header">Search words
            <form class="filterform" action="#">
                <input class="filterinput" type="text" id="filterinput">
            </form>
        </h3>
<ul id="list"  >
            <li><span><a>1</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a>12</a></span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span><a>23</a></span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span><a>33</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span><a>31</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span><a>35</a></span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span><a>14</a></span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span><a>23</a></span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span><a>34</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span><a>36</a></span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><span><a>24</a></span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span><a>32</a></span></li>
                                    <li><span><a>34</a></span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span><a>2</a></span></li>
        </ul>
```

and this is the jquery code:

```
    (function ($) {
    // custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
    jQuery.expr[":"].contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
        return function (elem) {
            return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };
    });

    // this function calls itself, to search in every level
    function hasChild(list) {
        // the searched value
        var filter = $('#filterinput').val();
        // for every children, do function:
        list.children('li').each(function () {
            // see if the list contains the filter
// if you don't want to use span,  you can  write the following function:
 //find("a:contains(" + filter + ")")
                        if ($(this).find("span > a:contains(" + filter + ")").length > 0) {
                            // see if it has nested levels
                            if ($(this).find('ul :first').length > 0) {
                                $(this).show();
                                // recall function
                                hasChild($(this).find('ul :first').parent());
                            } else {
                                $(this).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    });
                };
                $('#filterinput').keyup(function () {
                    // the id of the filtered list
                    var list = '#list';
                    // the searched value
                    var filter = $('#filterinput').val();
                    if (filter) {
                        // call previous function
                        hasChild($(list));
                    } else {
                        // show all
                        $(list).find("li").show();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            }(jQuery));
```