# List.js finds the element but still keeps others too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, list.js

its my first time using List.js. I have the following structure:

```js
var options = {
    valueNames: ['name']
};

var coursesList = new List('courses-list', options);

coursesList.on('updated', function(list) {
    console.info(list.matchingItems);
    if (list.matchingItems.length > 0) {
        $('.no-result').hide()
    } else {
        $('.no-result').show()
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
<div id="courses-list">
 <input class="search">
  <div id="collectionView" class="list">
    <div class="row1">
     <div class="large-6 small-12 columns" >
      <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
       <span class="name">Demokurs Französisch A2 Online</span>
       <p class="description">blabla</p>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 small-12 columns" >
     <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
      <span class="name">Französisch</span>
      <p class="description">blabla</p>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="row2">
     <div class="large-6 small-12 columns" >
      <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
       <span class="name">Kurs A</span>
       <p class="description">blabla</p>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 small-12 columns" >
     <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
      <span class="name">Kurs B<span>
      <p class="description">blabla</p>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Well now if I search for the term `A2` it show correctly the content of the firstdiv in `row1` **BUT** also the second div with all of its content. List.js hides `row2` as wished.

How can I make it work that it also hides all other divs in a row?

I have also checked if really only matching is there with:

```
coursesList.on('updated', function(list) {
    console.info(list.matchingItems);
    if (list.matchingItems.length > 0) {
        $('.no-result').hide()
    } else {
        $('.no-result').show()
    }
})
```

The logs show that `list.matchingItems` finds only object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List.js isn't designed to work this way, it [doesn't support nested lists](https://github.com/javve/list.js/issues/59), it only counts a list item down 1 level, so its sees the whole of the `<div class="row1">` as a single list item and `<div class="row2">` as another.

If you want it to work properly I suggest removing the `<div class="row1">` and`<div class="row2">` so that all the relevant `<div>` are at the same level. Like shown below:

```js
var options = {
    valueNames: ['name']
};

var coursesList = new List('courses-list', options);

coursesList.on('updated', function(list) {
    console.info(list.matchingItems);
    if (list.matchingItems.length > 0) {
        $('.no-result').hide()
    } else {
        $('.no-result').show()
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
<div id="courses-list">
  <input class="search">
  <div id="collectionView" class="list">
      <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
          <span class="name">Demokurs Französisch A2 Online</span>
          <p class="description">blabla</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
          <span class="name">Französisch</span>
          <p class="description">blabla</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
          <span class="name">Kurs A</span>
          <p class="description">blabla</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <a href="link/to/somewhere" target="_blank">
          <span class="name">Kurs B</span>
          <p class="description">blabla</p>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you absolutely require the nested lists then you should instead use jQuery,  [in a similar way to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922312/how-do-you-search-a-nested-list-with-jquery) and not use List.js.

Comment: This answer is exactly true. Because list.js filter affect only the children of first div with class="list". if you remove  id="collectionView" and change the div class="row1" to "row1 list", it works how you want but this does not work for second row div (class="row2 list, does not work).

Comment: Thx!  I have used your approach but combined it with multiple List.js lists. It helps to categorize different rows!